# How to drag/drop a hyperlink formula to link to Finished Goods #'s list on Sheet 1 to Raw Materials List on Sheet 2

Tags: excel, hyperlink, cell

On Sheet one, I have a column of Item Numbers for finished goods in column A. In Sheet two, I have a list of the name Finished Good numbers, but in a different order. Immediately following the list of of Finished good Items codes in Sheet 2 is a list of their raw materials.

I was thinking of creating a second column in Sheet 1 that would contain Hyperlinks to Jump to the Finished Good Item #'s in Sheet 2 based on the cell contents in Column A. Unfortunately, there a several thousands of these items, so doing manual cell references won't work. I would need a formula that would pick up the cell contents in Column A and jump to that number on Sheet 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1]Sheet2!A" & MATCH(A2;Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9;0)+1;A2)
```

And Autocomplete. 
**Considering:**

```
Book1 -> The name of your XLS file
Sheets -> The name of sheet you want to go
$B2$B9 -> The range of data in the sheet2
B -> The column of Index (To connect Sheet1 with Sheet2)
```

**Notes:**
1) The +1 after match it's the number of Header rows in the table
2) You go on the "A" cell of the row